# How to find out what argument values have been used in an R function call?

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there is an Base R function to extract the argument values that are in use in a particular function call?

For example, for each of the objects `x`, `y` and `z` below, is there a generic way to extract the arguments names (e.g., `n`, `sd`, `rate`, `scale`) in use and the values (e.g., `1e4` for `n`) assigned by the user or the system to each of those arguments?

**NOTE:** in certain "R" functions such extraction is easily done. For example, in `density()`, one can easily extract the argument `values` using `density()$call`.

```
 x = rnorm(n = 1e4, mean = 2, sd = 4)
 y = rlogis(1e4, 20)
 z = rexp(1e4, 5)
```

Comment: AFAIK, you'd have to save the call and parse it, which is kind of a pain.

Comment: as @alistaire said, you can access the call inside a function using `Sys.call()` ... But what's your goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really not an easy thing to do. If you're building the function, you can capture the call with `match.call`, which can be parsed without too much trouble:

```r
f <- function(x, y = 1, ...){
    cl <- match.call()
    as.list(cl[-1])
}

str(f(1))
#> List of 1
#>  $ x: num 1

str(f(1, 'foo'))
#> List of 2
#>  $ x: num 1
#>  $ y: chr "foo"

str(f(1, 'foo', list(3), fun = sum))
#> List of 4
#>  $ x  : num 1
#>  $ y  : chr "foo"
#>  $    : language list(3)
#>  $ fun: symbol sum
```

Note `match.call` only captures the call, and doesn't add in default parameters (there's no `y` in the first example). Those can be accessed with `formals(f)`, since `f` isn't primitive, so complete arguments could be created via

```r
user_args <- f(1)
fun_args <- formals(f)
fun_args[names(user_args)] <- user_args

str(fun_args)
#> List of 3
#>  $ x  : num 1
#>  $ y  : num 1
#>  $ ...: symbol
```

This approach doesn't work well for completed dots, but if they're completed then `match.call` itself should suffice. To extract the parameters passed to an existing function, you could write a wrapper with `match.call`, but it's hardly practical to reconstruct every function, and the call you capture will look funny anyway unless you overwrite existing functions. As long as the function isn't primitive, you could use `quote` to enable the `formals` approach, though:

```r
cl <- quote(rnorm(5, 2))
user_args <- as.list(cl[-1])    # subset call to only args
fun_args <- formals(as.character(cl[1]))    # subset call to only function
names(user_args) <- names(fun_args)[seq(length(user_args))]
fun_args[names(user_args)] <- user_args

str(fun_args)
#> List of 3
#>  $ n   : num 5
#>  $ mean: num 2
#>  $ sd  : num 1
```

Another approach is to use rlang, whose functions handle primitives well (`fn_fmls(sum)`), can extract parts of the call easily and reliably (`lang_fn`, `lang_args`), name unnamed parameters accurately (`lang_standardize`), and more. Together with purrr's new `list_modify` (dev version), it all becomes fairly painless:

```r
library(rlang)

fun_call <- quo(rnorm(5))
fun_call
#> <quosure: frame>
#> ~rnorm(5)

default_args <- fn_fmls(lang_fn(fun_call))
str(default_args)
#> Dotted pair list of 3
#>  $ n   : symbol 
#>  $ mean: num 0
#>  $ sd  : num 1

user_args <- lang_args(lang_standardise(fun_call))
str(user_args)
#> List of 1
#>  $ n: num 5

calling_args <- purrr::list_modify(default_args, user_args)
str(calling_args)
#> Dotted pair list of 3
#>  $ n   : num 5
#>  $ mean: num 0
#>  $ sd  : num 1
```

Comment: `match.call` seems to capture the current call from "within the function". When quoting a call such as `fun_call` from "outside", the modifications take place on a different level. Is it possible to capture a call "from within" a function via rlang also?

Comment: Sure. There are options, depending on exactly what you want, but you should be able to grab all the arguments with something like `f <- function(x, y = 1, ...) {c(as.list(rlang::get_env()), rlang::dots_list(...))}; f(1, z = 2)`