# How to extract default value set inside a function?

Tags: r, function

I have created the function `toy_fun`, and I am setting the default value of `c` *inside* the function.:

```r
toy_fun = function(a,b,c) {
  
  if(missing(c)) c = 1
  sum <- a + b + c
  sum
}
```

Indeed, if I call `toy_fun` with only two arguments, I get:

```r
toy_fun(1,1)
#> [1] 3
```

Now imagine that I can't access `toy_fun`'s script but I still want to know, after the fact, what are the arguments of `toy_fun` and what are their assigned and default values, if any.

I have tried the following approach, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235791/how-to-find-out-what-argument-values-have-been-used-in-an-r-function-call), but it does not gives me the value of `c`:

```r
library(rlang)

fun_call <- quo(toy_fun(1,1))

default_args <- fn_fmls(call_fn(fun_call))
str(default_args)
#> Dotted pair list of 3
#>  $ a: symbol 
#>  $ b: symbol 
#>  $ c: symbol

user_args <- call_args(call_standardise(fun_call))
str(user_args)
#> List of 2
#>  $ a: num 1
#>  $ b: num 1

calling_args <- purrr::list_modify(default_args, user_args)
str(calling_args)
#> Dotted pair list of 3
#>  $ a:List of 2
#>   ..$ a: num 1
#>   ..$ b: num 1
#>  $ b: symbol 
#>  $ c: symbol
```

**Question**

Is there a way of knowing what the value of `c` was set to?

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I know , I know this is not what you want, but you can try `body(toy_fun)`, you can further break it like this: `as.list(as.list(body(toy_fun))[[2]])[[3]]`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But why do you call `as.list` twice? `as.list(body(toy_fun))[[2]][[3]]` also works.

Comment: Break it like  this : `body(toy_fun)`, it will produce a internal script between curly braces, each element(line) is basically a list element, hence the first list, then within that list, the c sits at 3 position of second list, that is why

Comment: Right, but if I run `as.list(body(toy_fun))[[2]][[3]]` I still get the same results.

Comment: what is your expectation, it will return c=1

Comment: `as.list(body(toy_fun))[[2]][[3]]` returns `c = 2` and
`as.list(as.list(body(toy_fun))[[2]])[[3]]` also returns `c = 2`

Comment: The code inside the function that assigns to `c` can be arbitrarily complex. Short of executing the function body there is no *general* way of figuring out which value it’s being set to. Of course you can statically analyse `body(f)` as shown by PKumar, but this isn’t sufficient if the decision of what to assign `c` is done conditionally based on runtime conditions. Consider the contrived example `if (sample(2, 1) == 1) c = 1 else c = 2`. — So, since this isn’t possible in general,  can you explain more precisely what you need this for? There might be a solution for your specific use-case.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, thank you - my starting problem was that, in a much more complex function, I was getting two different results when using the same value of `c`; in one case I was setting `c=0` explicitly in the function call, in the other case I was letting it set inside the function as a missing value. I thought that the value of `c` was maybe being further modified in this more complex function, that's why I posted the question. Then I realized that *other parameters* were conditional on the way I was passing `c`. To get to that, I just returned all the parameters' values as a list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make the simplifying assumption that you just want to know what the arguments are at the end of the function. Consequently, if `c` is being modified again after the initial check for it being missing, this approach will capture that change as well.

```
myEnv <- new.env()

trace(
  toy_fun, 
  print = FALSE,
  exit = quote(
    assign(
      "fxArgs", 
      mget(names(formals(toy_fun))),
      envir = myEnv
    )
  )
)
```

`trace` modifies functions to run arbitrary code. In this case it will be code to capture the argument values and save them to an environment where they can be accessed later via `myEnv$fxArgs`.

Working from the inside outwards, `names(formals(toy_fun))` creates a character vector of the argument names so `mget` can retrieve them from the local function execution environment. These values are assigned to a predefined environment to take advantage of the pass-by-reference nature of environments. `trace` modifies `toy_fun` to execute this code on exit.

If you don't want later changes to `c`, you'll have to either know your specific function or find a way to find the line where it's first assigned. Once you know the line, you can add the trace after that line instead of on exit.